# RTMP / TCP extra byte in packet?

Tags: tcp, rtmp

I'm analyzing the RTMP(Real-Time Messaging Protocol) and found something really weird. In one of the captured packets, the TCP payload length is longer than expected. Here's the packet in Wireshark:
[image: Wireshark TCP payload view]

The `C3` byte makes the RTMP longer than expected. Which surprisingly gone in the RTMP payload view:

[image: Wireshark RTMP payload view]

As you can see, the `C3` byte disappeared in the RTMP view. But it is part of the TCP payload. I can't get an idea why this happen, I suspect:

1. Some longer UTF-8 character?

   According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format#AMF0), the string in AMF0 is encoded into 16-bit UTF-8. It means it can be either 8/16bit. However, `\u33C3` and `\uC32E` are both Korean characters, which shown in the second picture that it isn't my case.
2. Padding / escape character for TCP payload?

   Nah...I never heard about that...
3. Something about TCP that I don't know?

   Here's what I found:

   a. It wasn't a fragment of RTMP message, the TCP packet hold everything a RTMP message need.

   b. The checksum is good, everything seems good.

   c. The packet was correctly ACK-ed by peer (not shown in picture)

   d. This is reproduce-able, by using the streaming software Wirecast

Am I missing something here? Why could Wireshark correctly decode the payload? Why Wireshark simply remove the `C3` (that suggests it has nothing to do with AMF0 codec)? I'm so confuse. Please help :'(

RTMP protocol specifications here: https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I finally figured it out!
According to Adobe's document,

> The maximum chunk size defaults to 128 bytes

And

> **5.3.1.2.4. Type 3**
> Type 3 chunks have no message header...A stream consisting of messages of exactly the same size, stream ID and spacing in time SHOULD use this type for all chunks after a chunk of Type 2.

(**Chunk header, also named "chunk basic header", is not message header, they're completely different!**)

Here `type 3` refers to chunk header type 3, which sits in the first two bits of the first byte with value `0b11xxxxxx`. And the reset of six bytes are stream ID (it's 3 here, `0bxx000011`). These two statements match the behaviour of my question: new chunk on offset 128 bytes (message header not count) with chunk header `type 3`. And Wireshark did parse it correctly. A bit confusing: they don't consider chunk header as part of the message, which makes sense. But they did consider the type 0-2 chunk header as part of the message (the first `0x03`), which doesn't make sense.

Also, I found a reference here (search `C3` and...you get it...):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-Time_Messaging_Protocol